# How to check whether or not $g(x)$ is continuous

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ is twice-differentiable and $f(0)=1$. Let $$ g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(x)-e^x}{x}, & x \neq 0, \\ a, & x = 0.  \end{cases} $$
Question: (1) Find a value of $a$ such that $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. (2) For this value of $a$, is $g'(x)$ continuous at $x=0$?

My partial solution: $$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-e^x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} (f'(x) - e^x) = f'(0)-1.$$ But we don't know $f'(0)$. Thank you very much.

Comment: but you don't need it ! if $a=f'(0)-1$, $g$ is continuous, and if not, $g$ is not continuous.

Comment: How is the middle step justified? Where did $f'(x)$ come from? Where have you used $f(0)=1$?

Comment: @user2345215, that is L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @Michael Thank you! I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is given, so you don't need to worry about what $f'(0)$ is, your solution of $(1)$ is complete if you set $a=f'(0)-1$.

$(2)$ can be done similarly:
\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to0}g'(x)&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{f(x)-e^x}x\right)'=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(f'(x)-e^x)-(f(x)-e^x)}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x(1-x)-(f(x)-xf'(x))}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x(1-x)-e^x-(f'(x)-f'(x)-xf''(x))}{2x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{xf''(x)-xe^x}{2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)-e^x}2=\frac{f''(0)-1}2.\end{align*}
There's a theorem which says that if the limit of a derivative exists at a point $x_0$ and the function is continuous there, then the derivative at $x_0$ also exists and is equal to the limit, so we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Around $0$, $f(x) = f(0) + f^\prime(0)x + o(x) = 1 + f^\prime(0)x + o(x)$ (Taylor expansion), and similarly $e^x = 1 + x +o(x)$. Thus,
$$
\frac{f(x)-e^x}{x} \operatorname*{=}_{x\to 0} \frac{1 + f^\prime(0)x - 1 -x +o(x)}{x} = f^\prime(0) - 1 +o(1) \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} f^\prime(0) - 1
$$
To get continuity, you therefore need to have $a = \displaystyle\lim_0 f = f^\prime(0) - 1$.

For the second part, you can also use the same approach: compute the expression of $g^\prime(x)$ (well-defined) for $x\neq 0$, and use a Taylor expansion (to the second-order, until $o(x^2)$) around $0$ to see if the limit exists.